# ReactDOM.render not rendering all Id's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a simple React Chrome Extension and am struggling with some rendering issues. I haven't used vanilla JS in awhile so any help would be appreciated!

I have the following code below that replaces the word 'coronavirus' on any webpage. It also adds `id="root"` and `class="rainbow"`(which changes corona virus color) which I hope to render my App component to the id by: `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))`

```
replaceText(document.body);
function replaceText(element) {
    if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
        element.childNodes.forEach(replaceText);
    } else if (element.nodeType === Text.TEXT_NODE) {
        if (element.textContent.match(/coronavirus/gi)) {
            const newElement = document.createElement('span');
            newElement.innerHTML = element.textContent.replace(
                /(coronavirus)/gi,
                '<span id="root" class="rainbow">$1</span>'
            );
            const root = document.getElementById('root');
            element.replaceWith(newElement);
        }
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

my simple App component:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

A quick Google search of 'coronavirus' seems to only successfully render one of my app component. [image of google search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjbxF.png). When I inspected each coronavirus element it seems that each element has an `id="root"` and `class="rainbow"`.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With current code you are telling react to find the first element with id `root` and place your component there. `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

You need to tell react that for all elements matching a specific selector, you need to place there your component.

You can try searching by class name and then you need to iterate the `ReactDOM.render` function.

Check [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-cannon-il1i7)

I guess in your case it would be

```
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("rainbow");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, divs.item(i));
}
```